# Can d3 transform data, how to show the different aspects of the same data?

Tags: d3.js

I have some data like student+testpoints which i would like to plot. The test scores have a max. of 100 points, and min of 0. Like:

- John 56points
- Ann  72points
- and so on for all the students

I have the data nicely in an array. I would like to do a barplot, with 10 bars each corresponding to a 10 point ranges of testscores, so the first bar is 0-10, etc, the last one is 90-100, and I would like the height of the bar be the number of students who have their grades in that range.

My question is, can d3 do this for me with the data format I have, or I should transform my data, do the counting, and easily plot the new data? Or can it do it without transformation? What is the proper way of showing different aspects of the same data?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450

Comment: Thank you very much! I skipped layouts when reading about d3, well I should not have.